# How to stop JSCH logs for camel sftp consumer

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

My camel SFTP consumer connects to server every 10 seconds and during every connect it prints huge log messages as mentioned here.

> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,441 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> kex: client:
>   hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,441 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> kex: client:
>   none
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,441 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> kex: client:
>   none
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,441 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> kex: client:
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,441 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> kex: client:
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,441 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> kex:
>   server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,441 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> kex:
>   client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,443 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,444 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> expecting
>   SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,762 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,762 WARN 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> Permanently
>   added '11.11.11.11' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,763 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,763 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:34,763 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:35,079 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:35,391 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   Authentications that can continue:
>   publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:35,391 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> Next
>   authentication method: publickey
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:35,391 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH ->
>   Authentications that can continue: password
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:35,391 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> Next
>   authentication method: password
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:35,707 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> Authentication
>   succeeded (password).
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:36,662 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] Connected to
>   sftp://username@11.11.11.11:22
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:36,662 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] Connected and logged
>   in to: sftp://username@11.11.11.11:22
>
> 02-05-2016 20:48:38,539 INFO 
>   (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel
>   (camel-99) thread #117 -
>   sftp://username:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> Disconnecting
>   from 11.11.11.11 port 22

How can I stop these messages from appearing in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a logger like log4j, you can simply turn off the JSCH logging with the following line in your logger config:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations = OFF
```

Comment: Not a problem! I'm glad I helped you : )

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to change the logger config, the current Camel [sFTP documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sftp-component.html) mentions few options you can set on the endpoint:

- jschLoggingLevel
- readLockLoggingLevel
- runLoggingLevel

For example you can set:

```
sftp://user@myserver.mydomain.net:9921/path/to/folder?binary=true&jschLoggingLevel=WARN&readLockLoggingLevel=INFO&runLoggingLevel=WARN
```

You can tweak each category to fit your needs directly in the endpoint without changing the configuration of your logger.